# Probability that at least one other vehicle arrives between third and fourth var arrival.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-process

> Starting at $6$ a.m, cars, buses and motorcycles arrive at a highway
>   toll booth according to independent Poisson processes. Cars arrive
>   about once every $5$ minutes, buses about once every $10$ minutes and
>   motorcycles about once every $30$ minutes.
>
> Find the probability that at least one other vehicle arrives between
>   third and fourth car arrival.

If we let $Z_t$ be the number of buses and motorcycles in time interval $t$, we have that $Z_t\sim\text{Poi}(1/10 + 1/30)=\text{Poi}(2/15).$ We also know that the length of the internal time $T$ between cars is $\sim\text{exp(1/5)}.$

According to the book, they say that the sought probability is $P(Z_T>0)$ and they compute it as follows:

\begin{align}
P(Z_T>0)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(Z_T>0 \ | \ T=t)\cdot\frac{e^{t/5}}{5} \ dt=...\tag1
\end{align}

**Questions:**

1. I don't understand why we seek $P(Z_T>0).$ How does this ensure that we end up inbetween car $3$ and car $4$?
2. How do they get that integral? Is it that they are actually integrating the joint distribution of $Z$ and $T$ and then conditioning on $T$ and multiplying with its marginal distribution?

Comment: What is a "var arrival"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - In the context, possibly a typo for "car arrival"

Comment: This is very confusing.  "Find the probability that at least one other vehicle arrives between third and fourth var arrival."  The solution is obviously $0$.

Comment: var = car, excuse the typo :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why we seek $P(Z_T>0)$. How does this ensure that we end up inbetween car 3 and car 4?

$T$ is defined as the time between cars $3$ and $4$ arrivals (actually, the time between any  successive cars arrivals).

$Z_{t_1,t_2}$ is the number of buses and motorcycles in time interval $t_1 $ to $t_2$ . But because the process is homogeneous, the probability of this variable only depends on the interval length, so we call it $Z_t$ (with $t=t_2 - t_1$)

Then $Z_T$ is the number of buses and motorcycles that arrive between cars $3$ and $4$ arrivals.

> How do they get that integral? Is it that they are actually integrating the joint distribution of Z and T and then conditioning on T and multiplying with its marginal distribution?

Yes, basically. In general, $P(A)= \int P(A,B) dB=\int P(A |B) P(B) dB$ (marginalizaton and conditional probability). Think of $A$ as the indicator variable of the event of interest ($Z_t >0$) and $B$ as the interval length $T$.

Comment: So technically, $Z_T$ is the number of buses and motrocycles that arrive between ANY consecutive cars? Another quick question, say we already had the pdf of $Z$ and that $T$ was not a stochastic, then it would suffice to just use that $P(Z_T>0)=1-P(Z_T\leq0)=...$ right?

Comment: Yes to both.  BTW, this happens often: "if T were not a random variable but a constant, I'd know the answer - this means I know the answer conditioned on T - then... etc"